# Request works in one language but not in the other?

Tags: python, c#

Im sending a request to a api in python it worked but when i send the same request in c# it gives me {"error":"DENIED ACCESS"}

How would i fix this?

Python code:

```
 r = requests.post('https://client-api.arkoselabs.com/fc/gt2/public_key/KEYHERE', data= {
        'bda': '',
        'public_key': 'PUBLICKEY',
        'site': 'https://www.roblox.com',
        'userbrowser': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'
    })
    print(r.json())
```

C# Code

```
 var url = "https://client-api.arkoselabs.com/fc/gt2/public_key/PUBLICKEY";
    var newpost = new Post()
    {
        bda = "e30=",
        public_key = "PUBLICKEY",
        site = "https://www.roblox.com",
        userbrowser = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36"
    };
    var postJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newpost);
    var payload = new StringContent(postJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync(url, payload).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(response);
```

anybody know why?

I expected for the C# code to give me

```
{'token': '3626241effe061132.5620681005|r=eu-west-1|metabgclr=transparent|guitextcolor=%23474747|maintxtclr=%23b8b8b8|metaiconclr=transparent|meta=6|pk=SOMEKEY|at=40|atp=2|cdn_url=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com%2Fcdn%2Ffc|lurl=https%3A%2F%2Faudio-eu-west-1.arkoselabs.com|surl=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-api.arkoselabs.com'}
```

but it gave me {"error":"DENIED ACCESS"}

Comment: Please never share your keys, wasn't sure if they were good or not. I've updated your post to remove them, but anyone with the rep points can still see the edits. Please get a new key and don't use this one anymore, you don't want anyone to be using your key on your behalf.

Comment: After a quick look as well, in your python request you have `'bda': ''`, but in your `C#` version you have `bda = "e30="`...

Comment: use postman to see what actually sent. must be different.

Comment: if i add bda = "e30=" it still gives me the same thing

Comment: i used postman and everything worked it gave me the token but my code still wont work

Comment: I'm no expert on Python but it looks like using data= sends the provided tuple a as form encoded (bda=&public_key=...) but the C# version is sending as json payload?

Comment: Ends up, the two requests are clearly not the same, from what the server sees.. use whatever tool you have for web debugging (fiddler? Wire shark?) to examine the difference between what python sends (even headers, http method etc) and c# and make c's efforts mimic python more closely